# Unable to remove to Google chrome files

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, sudo

I installed google chrome a week ago and while using it when I go for a search it redirects me to Yahoo search or the app closes when search icon or enter button is pressed so I uninstalled Google chrome stable and also used autoremove to remove all file but in my ssd I still see old Google Chrome files and I reinstalled Google Chrome I see all errors are still there in the fresh install too, I think sudo apt-get autoremove is not working or there is some error I cant understand

Comment: Google chrome is installed inside '/opt/google/chrome'. If you remove chrome using apt and then delete that folder it should fully remove it.

Comment: what ?? I am confused I could find opt but it cannot be deleted or moved to the trash please help me! I am a new Linux user with very less experience

Comment: Find the Files app inside the Applications menu on the top left, and right click it. Press "New window as Administrator". If you go now to /opt/google/chrome you will be able to delete it.

Comment: I viewed it in files but here there is no delete option or move to trash, can I do something in terminal

Comment: Yes. There's a "Move to Trash" or "Delete Permanently" option when you right click on a folder. If the option is blurred out it means you didn't open Files as Admin.

Comment: Login files as Admin, how to do that ?? Thanks for your help 

Comment: `Find the Files app inside the Applications menu on the top left, and right click it. Press "New window as Administrator". ` If you have any issue doing that, let me know.

Comment: Could you add any screenshots because I tried and got frustrated there is no " new window as Admin" but there is only new window option 

Comment: I used the terminal to get admin access and deleted the files now need to see installing Chrome : )

Comment: I am confused why can't autoremove command remove unwanted files and I did intsall it again and now eaither it open yahoo search or closed the app why CHrome for linux bugged , In this process, I must have deleted any dir or important files of other apps How to fix missing as that command is showing an error 20.04

Comment: browser newly installed even has all the files and also Google acount signed in every time there is aproblem with Google chrome now I probably should resinstall ubuntu

Comment: Were you able to delete the chrome folder in the end? the command is `sudo rm -rf /opt/google/chrome`. Be careful with that command. If you set the folder incorrectly it may leave your system unusable!. Could you explain what error you see now? I am having some trouble understanding the issue.

Comment: Yes, I tried both Ubuntu and Mint while I use the Google Chrome one or another issue comes, earlier nothing like this was there but first problem came when I was editing my wordpress site left top was like old tv with some kind of glitch and so I installed Ubuntu and removed Mint as I am used to Ubuntu  and now in Ubuntu when I use Google it shows results in Yahoo and my search engine is still Google so I  removed Chrome and did apt autoremove and re installed Chrome but error was there and it was opening Chrome as before removing adn also all my accounts were loged in hope you understood

Comment: I will try the command and will respond is the issue resolved : ) Thanks for reading and your patience and helping me

Comment: No problem. Just note that you don't need to remove chrome to solve the issues that you are seeing. If you create a question with a screenshot of the issue I'm pretty sure a lot of people could help you.

Comment: Yeah The problem was that when I go for Google search Chrome was redirecting me it was a problem with an extension on Chrome which I removed and the issue was resolved but in case some new errors come to remove Google Chrome files its impossible, sorry that I could screenshot, thanks for your help :) but I have question in case we run sudo apt autoremove still files of removed application exist so what should a normal user do  who is noob like me in Linux

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /opt/google/chrome/ ` command was give and was successful but user data was not deleted which means after a fresh installation of Chrome all accounts were signed in and all things were same

Comment: is this help only for elementary OS or what is this elementary OS I am cureently using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: There's a folder inside `/home/[user]/.config/google-chrome` (change [user] for your username) that stores all your settings. You need to delete it as well. Or you can delete all your data from chrome settings directly. That will open chrome as a brand new installation.

Comment: Thanks : ), Hope it works. error in my chrome was caused by a bad extension that was malicious and redirected me to Yahoo but how to close this case.

Comment: @ExquisitE, You gave up on creating a working Windows installer drive in Ubuntu. You will probably feel more welcome at the [**Ubuntu Forums**](https://ubuntuforums.org), where I and several other people can help you, and we will not give up, as long as you stay with us.

Comment: I got so angry with windows that I completely removed windows from my laptop!

Comment: I been also forbidden from asking questions now and I'm facing some issues with 21.10 like it doesn't shut down or restart